# Retrieving host information inside jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

My host file for ansible looks as below

```
[deployment]
server1 ansible_ssh_host=x.x.x.x ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=abcdefg ansible_br_mgmt_ip=192.10.2.5 ansible_br_vlan_ip=192.10.4.5 ansible_br_vxlan_ip=192.10.8.5
server2 ansible_ssh_host=y.y.y.y ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=abcdefg ansible_br_mgmt_ip=192.10.2.6 ansible_br_vlan_ip=192.10.4.7 ansible_br_vxlan_ip=192.10.8.8
```

Inside jinja template (.j2 file) i am trying to retrieve the value of ansible_br_mgmt of server 1 or server 2

i tried the following ways , but couldnt get the exact IP address.

```
hostname: "{%  {{  hostvars['deployment'].ansible_br_mgmt_ip }} %}"

hostvars.deployment.ansible_br_mgmt_ip
groups['deployment'][ansible_br_mgmt_ip]
```

can you please help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- debug: msg={{ hostvars[groups['deployment'][0]].ansible_br_mgmt_ip }}
```

Output:

```
TASK: [debug msg={{ hostvars[groups['deployment'][0]].ansible_br_mgmt_ip }}] ***
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "192.10.2.5"
}
```